# Trying to get data from a video using YouTube's API and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using this snippet of jquery, but it's not working. I'm trying to get data from a video usign YouTube's API.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


var qid = 'cggNqDAtJYU';    
var youtubeAPI = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc';
$.get(youtubeAPI,{'q' : qid},function(response)){

       //data is the reponse
       var data = response.data;

      alert(data.duration);
   }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong query. It's not really a search, which is what the "q" parameter is used for, but rather a request for a specific video by its id. This works for me, with the data.duration returning a value of 831.

```
var youtubeAPI = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/cggNqDAtJYU?v=2&alt=jsonc';
$.get(youtubeAPI, function (response) {

    //data is the reponse
    var data = response.data;

    alert(data.duration);
});
```